# Подключаемся к VueJS проекту с большой кодовой базой. Какие есть инструменты для «code visalisation» чтобы ускорить изучение чужого кода командой?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, vue.js, vuex, vue-router

Подключаемся к VueJS проекту с большой кодовой базой. Ищем инструмент для "code visualisation" который бы ускорил изучение нового кода нашей командой.

Поиск выдает варианты вроде [StoryBook](https://storybook.js.org/) и [StyleGuidist](https://vue-styleguidist.github.io/) . Что бы вы посоветовали проверенное на практике?

В идеале хотелось еще и инструмент что показывало бы общую картину кода и взаимосвязи между частями кода.
Например как [ngRev](https://github.com/mgechev/ngrev) для Angular.